# Having multiple return URLs on one Relying Party Application on ACS Azure

Tags: azure, adfs, acs

I'd like to be able to specify the return URL of the ACS authentication when I redirect the user to his Identity Provider's log-in URL instead of the one I specified in the ACS management portal. I'll mainly be using ADFS IPs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by hosting your own home realm discovery (HRD) page. See option 2 here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx

You can download a working HRD page from the ACS portal and customize it's call to IdentityProviders.js, specifying the reply_to as you wish.